# What do these bash comments do

Tags: bash, scripts, documentation

I am learning bash. Nothing special, just tinkering around with my own scripts. It's great fun.

Looking at options to document your bash scripts, I came across this.

What is the significance of the double "##", and the tags "@var", "@brief" etc.

I am guessing I am missing a trick here.

```
## @var DEBUG
## @brief Enables / disables the debug mode.
## @details The debug mode adds extra information for troubleshooting purposes.
## Value: yes or no (y / n).
```

Comment: To be clear, comments don't mean anything to Bash itself. Special comments like this are processed by a different program (Doxygen, in this case). A [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) is also a special comment, but that's processed by the kernel.

Answer (score 8):

They are [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl) documentation commands. Doxygen can generate HTML and other format documentation. Those commands control how the documentation is formatted, eg. bolding text.

Comment: Yes. For the shell (_bash_, for example) they are just ordinary comments but Doxygen recognizes the keywords `@var`, `@brief`, `@details` within comments and can generate documentation from them.

Comment: I will take a look at Doxygen. I know there are also other tools that create documentation also. As a final quick question, is there a recommended tool to use, do most people use Doxygen ?

Comment: @hatterman I think most projects use Doxygen. Sphinx is also quite popular. I can't compare them, though, I've only used Doxygen.

Comment: Thanks. Ive staeted reading the docs, I will give it a whirl.

Answer (score 0):

Anything starting with a hash sign (#) is a comment.  It is like a `REM` in Windows batch or command file.  So, all of the lines that you show are comments.

If I had to guess, this was copied and pasted from a Windows batch file.  The @ in a Windows batch file means "do not echo out this line".  The @ in a Bash shell in this particular situation means nothing.

Comment: No, its from a Linux bash script. I know  the # is a comment.